# Why is my desktop suddenly using my home folder?

Tags: gnome, nfs, ldap

Installed gdm, using GNOME Classic. Also using LDAP for authentication and home folder designation.

I realized my home folder was set to `/home/users/ldapuser` which is undesired behavior, because that means my home folder will depend on which machine I'm logged into. This was after I already had a decent amount of information built up in my home folder. I edited the appropriate LDAP field to use the NFS share home directory, which is empty. I copied files from my machine into the NFS share to 'migrate' my info/settings etc.

Originally the Desktop was using `~/Desktop` as the Desktop folder which was fine with me. But now it seems after I've switched, it is simply using `~` as the Desktop folder. So, now I have a folder on my Desktop named 'Desktop' which has all the stuff that was on my original Desktop. Also, all the files from my home folder now appear on the Desktop, the whole situation is very disconcerting.

How can I get the interface to treat `~/Desktop` as the actual Desktop directory again, and why did it change?

Comment: It would be great if anyone could give me a hint at least

Answer (score 0):

`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/user-dirs.dirs` was determining that my desktop should be `$HOME` instead of `$HOME/Desktop`.

The rest of my folders were also set to `$HOME`, which is why they were gone, which I didn't even realize until now.

Not sure how it happened, but changing these values back fixed the problem.